# Building a web app with Dropbox for file storage

Tags: web-applications, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

We're building a web app for which we'd like to use dropbox as image storage. Basic idea is to have users work in teams. A team represents a real world company. Each team has its own Dropbox account owned by the company.

Users log into our web app and can see their teams' shared images. We don't want individual users to know the Dropbox account credentials - the account is owned by the company. Now we come to the technical problem - how do we ship those images from our web application to the users browser?

1. I'd prefer if we could somehow directly ship it from Dropbox servers to the users' browser. That would imply somehow transferring the oauth token from the server to the users browser. Not sure if this is even legal :-) Alternatively, we could generate a publicly available URL for each of the images and ship that URL to the users browser. I don't think that's a good practice from the privacy perspective.
2. We can do it through our server - our server reads data form Dropbox and ships it to the users' browser. That way our app has the oauth token and picks all needed data from dropbox and ships it to the client. A problem with that approach is the unnecessary load going through our server - we pick the image up from dropbox and ship it to the user.

Did anyone else have a similar problem? What would be the best approach to this? We don't want to switch image storage provider - let's just say our users want it to be Dropbox :-)